# selectively override name records in a public domain via private hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

If I wanted to override a single name record for a public domain I do not manage but still resolve other records in that domain, how would I achieve that?

For instance photos.google.com & maps.google.com. In my vpc if I wanted to allow ec2 to resolve photos.google.com correctly, but I wanted calls to maps.google.com to resolve to an IP local to my vpc, is that possible via Route53?

I know I could create a private hosted zone "google.com" associate it and then create a record for maps.google.com that points to my custom endpoint, but then calls to photos.google.com would fail with NXDOMAIN.

Comment: "but then calls to photos.google.com would fail with NXDOMAIN." That has not been my experience. Have you actually tested that?

Comment: yes, that is the behaviour i've seen, just recreated it as well with a hosted zone google.com. I added a record for maps.google.com as an A record pointing a private ip address and did not add a record for photos.google.com and got NXDOMAIN

Comment: Or, just use `/etc/hosts` to override the DNS process for those domains.

Comment: I see. I think the reason I saw different behavior was because both the public and private domains were in Route53. What about creating a Route53 private zone for the subdomain only `photos.google.com` instead of creating one for the root domain?

Comment: @MarkB i wasn't sure if that would work, can you create a C record that is the sub domain itself? i'll try that out.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i need to manage it via R53 as opposed to a config management utility like ansible or config mgr.

Comment: I don't know what a `C` record is. I assume you mean `CNAME`? In any case, you would use an `A` record instead of `CNAME` for that. You would either use a Route53 alias to your EC2 instance or whatever, or you would use an IP address value.

Comment: @MarkB yes, sorry, CNAME record. The target isn't managed in our aws account, so we can't alias an A record and can't necessarily use an IP address. Regardless though, I think this will work.